# R - file.copy function

Tags: r, copy

As part of a larger script, I need to move all <.csv> files from one directory to another. I wrote a simple script to do it, and was working fine, but for some reason, it is not working now, and I am going nuts trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code is:

```
rawPath <- "./test_dir1"
dataPath <- "./test_dir2"

dataFiles <- dir(rawPath, "*.csv", ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)
file.copy(dataFiles, dataPath, overwrite = TRUE )
```

But I get the following error:

> Warning messages:
>   `1: In file.copy(dataFiles, dataPath, overwrite = TRUE) :
>     problem copying .\test_dir1\11085.lis.csv to C:\Users\Desktop\test_dir2\11085.lis.csv: No such file or directory`

`One error message for each file`

Please, find trial directories and files that are a simplified version of what I have in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7eqvyugc472w19i/AACIjlytbB4s55X0Ga1hmKQka?dl=0

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that you have extracted the file names relative to `rawPath`, and then are trying to use that in `file.copy` while you're in a different directory. Running your code, look at `dataFiles`:

```
dataFiles
# [1] "11085.lis.csv" "13087.lis.csv" "17089.lis.csv" "5081.lis.csv"  "7083.lis.csv"
```

You want

```
file.copy(paste(rawPath, dataFiles, sep = .Platform$file.sep), dataPath, overwrite = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Or alternatively:

```
file.copy(file.path(rawPath, dataFiles), dataPath, overwrite = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**To reproduce:**

```
dir.create("test_dir1")
dir.create("test_dir2")
files <- paste0(c(5081, 7083, 11085, 13087, 17089), ".lis.csv")
file.create(paste("test_dir1", files, sep = .Platform$file.sep))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

dir("test_dir1")
# [1] "11085.lis.csv" "13087.lis.csv" "17089.lis.csv" "5081.lis.csv"  "7083.lis.csv" 
dir("test_dir2")
# character(0)

rawPath <- "./test_dir1"
dataPath <- "./test_dir2"
dataFiles <- dir(rawPath, "*.csv", ignore.case = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)

# To reproduce the error:
file.copy(dataFiles, dataPath, overwrite = TRUE )

# To run without error:
file.copy(file.path(rawPath, dataFiles), dataPath, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: It works! great!! So the problem was that I was not defining the entire 'source' path, just providing a list of files, is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: @ebb that's correct. `file.copy` runs in your working directory. It will look for the filenames in that directory, when you want to look for them in `rawPath`

Comment: that makes so much sense now. That is why it was working on a previous script but not in this one. The source file was the working directory in that case but not here. I learned a lot, thanks again.

Comment: Maybe using the argument  full.names = TRUE inside list.files() command might help in finding the files, regardless the directory or project you are in.